# I have encounter with error when I run the applicaction

Tags: java

It says Build; failed,"Process unexpectedly exit." I try to change gradle dependencies from 3.6.1 to 3.6.0 but it didnt work it in both. I am using latest version of android studios 3.6.

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\RawMiz Thapa\AndroidStudioProjects\GridView

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
>   Task :app:compileDebugShaders
>   Task :app:generateDebugAssets
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Multiple task action failures occurred:
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-6040484-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-6040484-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-6040484-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-6040484-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-6040484-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-6040484-windows Daemon #8: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-6040484-windows Daemon #9: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.0-6040484-windows Daemon #10: Daemon startup failed
  >       Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
10 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 7 up-to-date

Comment: This question seems awfully familiar... haven't I seen this one today already?